# Symfony2 - Doctrine - Join 2 tables

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm having issues setting up my Doctrine request properly.
I have two tables (PROPRIETE and PHOTO), one PROPRIETE can have many PHOTO

Therefore, I'd like to make a SELECT that will return an array of PROPRIETE where which one includes an array of it's own PHOTOs (not sure if I'm clear though...)

This is what my Popriete class looks like

```
class Propriete
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="libelle", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $libelle;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VillaPrivee\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $proprietaire;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="VillaPrivee\MainBundle\Entity\Photo", mappedBy="propriete")
     */
    private $photo;
```

And then the Photo class

```
class Photo
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VillaPrivee\MainBundle\Entity\Propriete")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $propriete;
```

And finally, my Doctrine request (that successfully returns a list of Propriete, but nothing about their photos)

```
public function getProprietesByCriteria($ville, $rooms) {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $qb->where('p.commune = :ville AND p.nbChambres >= :rooms')
                ->setParameter('ville', $ville)
                ->setParameter('rooms', $rooms);
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

I've tried with a leftJoin, but it seems that I don't know how to use that stuff...
Thanks guys for your help

Comment: If you invoke the method `getPhoto()` on any of the returned `PROPRIETE` values, do you get the `PHOTO` array?

Answer (score 0):

I thing you're mixing different concepts in your code. Using `Doctrine` you should forget about trying to get multiple arrays with a query.

You only need to invoke the `getPhoto()` method on any `propriete` object.

So, you can use a code similar to:

```
$props = $this->getProprietesByCriteria($ville, $rooms);
foreach($props as $prop)
{
  $prop->getPhoto(); // <--will return an array of the `PHOTO` related to this `PROPIETE`
}
```